# How to access mysql alias value using php mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch mySQL value using php, but it doesn't work. I use alias in my query. Here's my code :

```
$selectedFeature = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM(SELECT * FROM token_preprocessing_latih WHERE id_term<=5112 ORDER BY tf_idf_normalisasi DESC) AS selectedFeature GROUP BY term ASC")or die(mysqli_error($db)); 

    $feature = $feature*100;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectedFeature)) {
        $term = $row['term'];
        $bobot = $row['tf_idf_normalisasi'];

        mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO selected_feature VALUES('','$term','$bobot','$feature')")or die(mysqli_error($db));
    }
```

I've check `$term` and `$bobot` value on my database. It shows my query has inserted the wrong value. Can someone tell me how to fix it ? Thank you.

Comment: `print_r($row)`

Comment: I printed it out, but the value is not as expected.

Comment: then the query is wrong

Comment: Do u have still problems?

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu no, I made a mistake on my query. Now it's work as expected.